# MARS MIPS Simulator Installation

Tags: windows-10, ide, assembly

I installed [MARS](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/) on my computer (ASUS) and when I tried to open it, it leads me to a dialog box which asks:

`"How do you want to open this .jar file?"`

I don't know how to figure it out.
Thanks for any help.

---

*Screenshot*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the dialog screenshot you provided, you will likely wish to keep the first option highlighted and press `OK`. Java (`javaw.exe`) is typically used to run Java Archive (`.jar`) files. The other options aren't intended to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Make sure you have the latest or at least not too old version of  [jdk](https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html) installed. Then set the environment variables as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJ-PJbvJBGs&t=246s). This worked for me.

Comment: One shouldn't have to manually set the environment variables.

Comment: I had to do in my case because I had two different versions of jdk (one old and one new) but the environment variable was set to the old one. After changing that to the new one it worked.